# python: create string with various parameters

Tags: python-3.x

How can I create a string where the parameters can be none.

```
def create_string(main_val, test_val=None, test_val2=None)
  return '%s-some_values: %s/%s/' % (main_val, test_val if test_val else '', testval2 if testval2 else '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working, just you messed up the variable name. You defined the variable as `test_val2` but you're using it as `testval2`.
Consider using the same name for your variables.